# Remove mobile view, but keep responsiveness?

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design

I have a theme, where i would like to keep a responsive design, but still make it act non-responsive on mobile devices, and control size trough viewport instead. Tried to fiddle with bootstrap and responsive.css, but couldn't make it work. I can swith the responsiveness off on the theme, but of course i loose the scalability on desktop, which i want to keep.

Any ideas how to make that happend?

Site: www.abovebasics.com

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you set a min-width of 320px to the body tag, for mobile view? That way the responsiveness will only work upto a width of 320px and anything less that will have a scroll bar.

Comment: Im not sure if i read this wrong, but i want the opposite? I want to turn OFF the responsiveness for mobile view. And to set a mobile view on the body tags, your talking something in line with @media only screen?

Comment: I am taking about using media queries to set a minimum width to your body tag, so the responsive behavior stops an specific width. This is what I meant to say:http://codepen.io/nighrage/pen/gJdeu/. I am now not sure if this is what you wanted.